# Axon - Consume Event from another Microservice

Tags: java, spring, microservices, axon

I have defined a Microservice:

**AccountManagementService**

- Handles CreateAccountCommand
- CreateAccountCommand shoots AccountCreatedEvent
- The new Account is then stored in mysql db
- Axon Server is used to store the event

Now I want another microservice B (that is connected to the same Axon Server) to handle the AccountCreatedEvent too.

[image]

Can I simply put

```
@EventHandler
protected void on(AccountCreatedEvent event){
}
```

in the second microservice B (for example in an Aggregate)? I tried that under the assumption that the event is stored in Axon Server and my second microservice automatically listens to that published event. It didn't work unfortunately.

How can microservice B subscribe to events (published by AccountManagementService) in the Axon Server?

Answer (score 1):

The key issue you are expiriencing stems from one of your final sentences:

> Can I simply put [insert-code-snippet] in the second microservice B (for example in an Aggregate)?

Well, yes you can simply add an `@EventHandler` annotated function in a regular component, but *not* in an Aggregate. The Aggregate functionality provided by Axon Framework is aimed towards being a Command Model. As would be used when employing [CQRS](https://axoniq.io/resources/cqrs) really.

This makes the Aggregate a component which can *solely* handle command messages.

The only exception to this, is when you are adding [Event Sourcing](https://axoniq.io/resources/event-sourcing) in the mix too. When Event Sourcing, you will source a given Command Model based on the events it has published. Thus introducing an `@EventSourcingHandler` annotated function inside your aggregate will only ever handle the events which originated from it.

To circle back to your original question, yes you can simply put the:

```java
@EventHandler
protected void on(AccountCreatedEvent event){
    // My event handling operation
}
```

in (micro)service B. But, that method **cannot** reside in an Aggregate. This is by design, to follow the CQRS and Event Sourcing paradigm as intended.

Any other component will do just fine though. If you are combining Axon with Spring, simply having the components with your event handling functions is sufficient. If you are not using Spring, you will have to register your components with event handlers to the `Configurer` or `EventProcessingConfigurer`.

Hoping this clarifies things for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using Spring.

So is there are way for Microservice B to subscribe to Events (from AccountManagementService) published to Axon Server, or do I still have to use an additional message broker like RabbitMQ to send events from AccountManagementService to Microservice B?

Comment: Yes there is definitely a way to get that going just with Axon Server! If both your microservices connect to the Axon Server instance you have running, you should be all set actually.

Comment: I created two seperate microservices, both are connected to Axon Server:

https://abload.de/img/unbenanntvtj7o.png

The first Microservice publishes an event, but the second microservice doesnt't seem to handle it. 

I put an EventHandler inside a Component into the second Microservice. Do I have to manually configure the second Microservice to listen to the events published to the Axon Server or do I have to configure the Axon Server itself? I can't seem to find Docs on that topic.

Comment: Well, in essence you shouldn't have to do that much at all... If you have default configured Axon Framework applications, they will automatically assume a default configured Axon Server instance. Furthermore, you'd thus have `TrackingEventProcessors` for your event handling components, which will on their own retrieve events from Axon Server. Without more configuration from your end, I'd find it hard to deduce why a basic set up isn't working in your scenario... What you could do, is take a look at this demo app from AxonIq, which definitely works: https://github.com/AxonIQ/hotel-demo